# react router link changing url but not the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

when i use link on my navbar component it changes the url but does not change the component, but it changes component when i reload,when i put link in main app.js it routes perfectly

app.js

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar/Navbar'
import About from './About/About'
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router ,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
function App() {
return (
  <div>
      <Navbar/>
  
    <Router>
       <Link to="/about">about</Link>
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/about">
      <About/>
    </Route>
    </Switch>
   </Router>
</div>

 );
  }

export default App;
```

navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import { Link, Router, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
    return (
       <div>
        <nav className="navbar">
            <div>
            <h1 className="nav_text">ExportGrains</h1>
            </div>
            <ul className="nav_ul">
                <BrowserRouter>
                <Link to="/about">about</Link>
                <li id="nav_li">HOME</li>
                <li id="nav_li">PRODUCTS</li>
                <li id="nav_li">ABOUT</li>
                <li id="nav_li">CONTACT</li>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
)
}

export default Navbar
```

about.js

```
 import React from 'react'

 function About() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>about page</h1>
        </div>
     )
}

 export default About;
```

it would be very kind if you can help me with it

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
import About from "...."
....
....
<Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one single `Router` for all your routes. The problem is that navbar is using different router and your other components are inside another router. So remove the router inside navbar and use single router inside your app component.

Also you can add `Navbar` as default route and put it at the end of the `switch` so that it matches when none of the above routes are matching.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Navbar />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

> Switch renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
> location.

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div>
          <h1 className="nav_text">ExportGrains</h1>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav_ul">
            <Link to="/about">about</Link>
            <li id="nav_li">HOME</li>
            <li id="nav_li">PRODUCTS</li>
            <li id="nav_li">ABOUT</li>
            <li id="nav_li">CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```